# Comma Code Python Project Error

Tags: python-3.x

So I searched around the forum for an answer to this question but I only came across very complicated data that I don't think the book "How to Automate stuff with Python" has covered. This is why I'm asking this question. I created a very simple function that can do as the project wants but I'm not sure how it would apply to every list. Could anyone advice?

> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example, passing the below spam list to the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

for i in spam:
    print(spam[0] + ', ' + spam[1] + ', ' + spam[2] + ', ' + 'and '+ spam[3]
```

Comment: This will print "apples, bananas, tofu, cats" four times.

Comment: What is the _project_? What is expected output?

Comment: Since you don't want join, I deleted my answer. You can look for, _for loop_ tutorials. :)

Comment: @Lafexlos Also, is it common to feel lost when doing such projects? I'm only on chapter 4 and I don't even know where to start when I get such projects and often look online for support :/

Comment: @icurryx3 that's normal and that's why those projects are for. After completing couple and getting the grasp of concepts, you'll have an idea how to start. It is just getting experince.